# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable при попытке посчитать нули в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Код:**

```
def move_zeros(array):
    a = array.count(0)
    for i in a:
        array.remove(0)
        array.append(0)
    return array
```

**Вопрос:**
При попытке пересчитать количество нулей в списке array программа выдаёт ошибку:

```
for i in a:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
a = array.count(0) # a - число. Количество нулей в массиве
for i in a: # у числа нет итератора
    # do smth
```

Если вам нужно `a` раз пройти цикл, используйте функцию `range`:

```py
a = array.count(0) # a - число
for i in range(a):
    # do smth
```

А вообще для фильтрации нулей лучше воспользоваться функцией `filter`:

```
>>> def cls(array):
...   count = array.count(0)
...   return list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, array)) + [0]*count
...
>>> cls([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 0, 7, 2])
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Замечание для автора: переменная `i` внутри цикла, как таковая, не используется. В таких случаях переменную традиционно называют `_`. Т.е. цикл будет иметь вид `for _ in range(a)`. С точки зрения работы программы это не меняет ничего, но увеличивает читабельность кода